# Broken ANGLE-generated HLSL from webgl shader

Tags: glsl, webgl, three.js, hlsl

I have an issue with a webgl shader that I've determined is related to ANGLE because it only occurs on Windows in Firefox or Chrome, and it doesn't happen if I force opengl (chrome --use-gl=desktop).

I've [created a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QPaRF/4/) that shows ANGLE-generated HLSL of my custom shader.  (for hlsl conversion to work in this jsfiddle, you must run chrome with --enable-privileged-webgl-extensions, or [just see my gist](https://gist.github.com/4201220) of the output)

So I have working glsl and the generated hlsl compiles but doesn't do the same thing.  The symptom is that on Windows, the vertices appear in correct initial locations, but do not move although I change the uniform `jed`.  I can't find the bug in the generated code.

Any tips for debugging problems like this?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say based on your info (including no original GLSL). It's not hard to imagine this being fixed by the July 4 revisions to ANGLE, however. I would say update, first.

Comment: My original glsl is in the jsfiddle linked in the post, but I've also posted it here separately: https://gist.github.com/4209605.  I'm using the latest version of chrome.  Would that have the revision of ANGLE you refer to?  Thanks!